# SimpleSAML_exception_handler() must be an instance of Exception, instance of Error given

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, php-7, apache2.4, simplesamlphp

I'm trying to test authenticate my SimpleSAML IDP installation with Google, but unfortunately I am received the following error log:

> ...SimpleSAML_exception_handler() must be an instance of Exception,
>   instance of Error given in simplesamlphp/www/_include.php:32\nStack
>   trace:\n#0 [internal function]...

The line this is referring to begins with the following;

```
function SimpleSAML_exception_handler(Exception $exception){
    if ($exception instanceof SimpleSAML_Error_Error) 
    {
            $exception->show();
    } 
    else 
    {
            $e = new SimpleSAML_Error_Error('UNHANDLEDEXCEPTION', $exception);
            $e->show();
    }
}
set_exception_handler('SimpleSAML_exception_handler');
```

I am running Ubuntu 16.04, Apache 2.4.18, PHP 7.0, SimpleSAML 1.14.

Answer (score 0):

You need to upgrade to SSP 1.14.5. According to the [change log](https://simplesamlphp.org/docs/1.14/simplesamlphp-changelog#section_12)

> Fixed the exception handler to be compatible with PHP 7.

There are further improvements for php 7 compatibility in later versions of SSP, so you are better off installing the latest version.